# Cluster words into groups of similar meaning (synonyms)

Tags: nlp, clustering, word-embeddings, text, semantic-similarity

**How can words be clustered into groups of similar meaning (synonyms)?**

I started with **pre-trained word embeddings** (e.g., [Google News](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/)), which is great, but not perfect - a limitation arises because the word embeddings are based on surrounding words. This introduces challenging results. For example:

- **polar meanings**: word embeddings might find opposites to be similar. Even though these words mean the opposite semantically, they can quite readily be interchanged given the same preceding and following words. For example, "*terrible*" and "*fantastic*" are easily interchangeable in the following sentence: "*I heard some ____ news today*". Another example is "*happy*" and "*unhappy*" in the following sentence: "*I was very ____ with the service*".
- **euphemisms**: word embeddings may find euphemistic words and doublespeak to be similar. Even though these words are perceived very differently, they can still readily be interchanged given the same preceding and following words. For example, "*headstrong*" and "*stubborn*" are easily interchangeable in the following sentence: "*He is a ____ colleague*". Other examples are: "*pamper/spoil*", "*check out/perv*", etc.

Is there a way to separate similar words (in a word-embeddings sense) into more **semantic clusters**?

---

**Possible solution?** Make one extra dimension that puts the word on a **sentiment spectrum**? This one dimension might be enough to sufficiently separate "terrible" from "fantastic", and "happy" from "unhappy", etc.

How might such a feature be engineered?

Note that many words would be "neutral" and so this additional dimension wouldn't really affect them. For example, "*Python/R/C++/Java*" in the following sentence: "*5+ years experience of ____ required*".

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to find synonyms by starting with word embeddings. Word embeddings group words by co-occurrence. For example "and" and "but" will be near each other in embedding space, even though those words have opposite meanings.

One option to find semantic clusters is to use WordNet, a large lexical database of English. WordNet models the meaning of the words.